# Arquivo FXML parou de abrir com o scene builder

Tags: java, javafx

Até ontem quando eu estava mexendo abria numa boa meu arquivo. Aí agora não abre mais meu arquivo. Os outros fxml do projeto abrem normalmente porém esse em especifico aparece o ícone ali em baixo que está aberto mas se eu clicar, não abre nenhuma janela. Alguém sabe o que é?

Este é o código do meu FXML

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="painelGeral" focusTraversable="true" 
prefHeight="839.0" prefWidth="884.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="exetiquetadora.janelasFXML.FXMLTelaPrincipalController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@fxml.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btnSincroniza" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="97.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sincronizar com Excellent Sistemas" />
      <Label layoutX="272.0" layoutY="20.0" text="Impressor de Etiquetas">
         <font>
            <Font size="37.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Pane fx:id="painelPrincipal" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="155.0" prefHeight="678.0" 
prefWidth="856.0">
         <children>
            <ScrollPane layoutX="25.0" layoutY="88.0" prefHeight="202.0" 
prefWidth="796.0">
               <content>
                  <TableView fx:id="tblResultProdutos" prefHeight="200.0" 
prefWidth="794.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="columnNome" prefWidth="257.0" text="Nome 
Produto" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="columnVProd" prefWidth="85.0" text="Valor 
Produto" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="columnCodEAN" minWidth="0.0" 
prefWidth="91.0" text="Cod EAN" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="columnOBS" prefWidth="97.0" text="OBS" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="columnCodReduzido" prefWidth="100.0" 
text="Cód.Reduzido" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="columnTamanho" prefWidth="81.0" 
text="Tamanho" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="columnCor" prefWidth="81.0" text="Cor" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <Button fx:id="btnLimparTabela" layoutX="627.0" layoutY="647.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#limparItens" text="Limpar Itens" />
            <Button fx:id="btnImprimir" layoutX="712.0" layoutY="647.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#imprimir" text="Imprimir" />
            <Button fx:id="btnPesquisar" layoutX="571.0" layoutY="50.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#pesquisarProdutos" text="Pesquisar" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtPesquisar" layoutX="268.0" layoutY="50.0" 
prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="289.0" />
            <ScrollPane layoutX="23.0" layoutY="469.0" prefHeight="172.0" 
prefWidth="810.0">
               <content>
                  <TableView fx:id="itensToPrint" prefHeight="170.0" 
prefWidth="1040.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="codigoPrint" prefWidth="75.0" text="Código" 
/>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="descricaoPrint" prefWidth="161.0" 
text="Descrição" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="valorPrint" prefWidth="56.0" text="Valor" 
/>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="qtdePrint" prefWidth="63.0" 
text="Qtde.Etiquetas" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="empresaPrint" prefWidth="76.0" 
text="Empresa" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="complementoPrint" prefWidth="89.0" 
text="Complemento" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="tamanhoPrint" prefWidth="63.0" 
text="Tamanho" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="codRedPrint" prefWidth="75.0" 
text="Cod.Reduzido" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="info1Print" prefWidth="70.0" text="Info1" 
/>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="info2Print" prefWidth="71.0" text="Info2" 
/>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="info3Print" prefWidth="83.0" text="Info3" 
/>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="corPrint" prefWidth="75.0" text="Cor" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="referenciasPrint" prefWidth="75.0" 
text="Referencias" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <Button fx:id="addItemToPrint" layoutX="732.0" layoutY="435.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addToPrint" text="Adicionar Item" />
            <Label layoutX="40.0" layoutY="302.0" text="Qtd. Etiquetas:" />
            <Label fx:id="lblCodBarras" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="412.0" text="Cód. de 
Barras:" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtCodBarras" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="408.0" />
            <Label layoutX="690.0" layoutY="412.0" text="Valor:" />
            <Label layoutX="611.0" layoutY="412.0" text="Cifrão:" />
            <TextField disable="true" layoutX="645.0" layoutY="408.0" prefHeight="22.0" 
prefWidth="26.0" promptText="R$" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtValor" layoutX="719.0" layoutY="408.0" 
prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="58.0" />
            <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="438.0" text="OBS:Inserir textos apenas sem 
acentuação" textFill="RED">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold Italic" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="346.0" layoutY="435.0" text="Itens para imprimir" 
textFill="#39ae35">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Bookshelf Symbol 7" size="21.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="txtQtd" layoutX="116.0" layoutY="298.0" prefHeight="22.0" 
prefWidth="42.0" promptText="0" />
            <Button fx:id="btnSair" layoutX="775.0" layoutY="647.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sair" text="Sair" />
            <Separator layoutX="18.0" layoutY="13.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="796.0" 
/>
            <Separator layoutX="22.0" layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="14.0" 
prefWidth="796.0" />
            <Label fx:id="lblTamanho" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="332.0" text="Tamanho:" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtTamanho" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="328.0" 
prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="42.0" />
            <Label fx:id="lblInfo1" layoutX="294.0" layoutY="339.0" text="Informação 
1:" />
            <Label fx:id="lblInfo2" layoutX="294.0" layoutY="375.0" text="Informação 
2:" />
            <Label fx:id="lblInfo3" layoutX="294.0" layoutY="412.0" text="Informação 
3:" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtInfo1" layoutX="368.0" layoutY="335.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtInfo2" layoutX="368.0" layoutY="371.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtInfo3" layoutX="368.0" layoutY="408.0" />
            <Label fx:id="lblEmpresa" layoutX="563.0" layoutY="302.0" text="Nome 
Empresa:" />
            <Label fx:id="lblComplemento" layoutX="559.0" layoutY="339.0" 
text="Complem. Nome:" />
            <Label fx:id="lblProduto" layoutX="601.0" layoutY="375.0" text="Produto:" 
/>
            <TextField fx:id="txtCodReduzido" layoutX="368.0" layoutY="298.0" />
            <Label fx:id="lblCodReduzido" layoutX="291.0" layoutY="302.0" text="Cód. 
Reduzido:" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtEmpresa" layoutX="645.0" layoutY="298.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtComplemento" layoutX="645.0" layoutY="335.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtProduto" layoutX="645.0" layoutY="371.0" />
            <Label fx:id="lblCor" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="357.0" text="Cor:" />
            <Label fx:id="lblReferencias" layoutX="56.0" layoutY="382.0" 
text="Referencias:" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtCor" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="353.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtReferencias" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="382.0" />
            <Label fx:id="lblTamCor" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="357.0" text="(0)" />
            <Label fx:id="lblTamReferencias" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="386.0" text="(0)" 
/>
            <Label layoutX="255.0" layoutY="412.0" text="(13)" />
            <Label fx:id="lblTamInfo3" layoutX="504.0" layoutY="412.0" text="(0)" />
            <Label layoutX="779.0" layoutY="412.0" text="(10)" />
            <Label fx:id="lblTamProduto" layoutX="779.0" layoutY="375.0" text="(0)" />
            <Label fx:id="lblTamComplemento" layoutX="779.0" layoutY="339.0" text="(0)" 
/>
            <Label fx:id="lblTamEmpresa" layoutX="779.0" layoutY="302.0" text="(0)" />
            <Label fx:id="lblTamInfo2" layoutX="504.0" layoutY="375.0" text="(0)" />
            <Label fx:id="lblTamInfo1" layoutX="504.0" layoutY="339.0" text="(0)" />
            <Label fx:id="lblTamCodReduzido" layoutX="504.0" layoutY="302.0" text="(0)" 
/>
            <Label fx:id="lblTamTamanho" layoutX="171.0" layoutY="332.0" text="(02)" />
            <Pane layoutX="38.0" layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="186.0" 
style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-background-color: silver;">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="7.0" text="Pesquisa por:" />
                  <RadioButton fx:id="rdDescricao" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="27.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Descrição" />
                  <RadioButton fx:id="rdCodigo" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="26.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" text="Código" />
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Button fx:id="btnEditar" layoutX="578.0" layoutY="435.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#editarLinha" text="Editar Linha Selecionada" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <Label layoutX="800.0" layoutY="60.0" text="Versão 1.0.4.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="12.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <Separator layoutX="8.0" layoutY="122.0" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="863.0" />
      <Separator layoutX="8.0" layoutY="77.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="863.0" />
      <Separator layoutY="11.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="863.0" />
      <ProgressBar layoutX="233.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="457.0" 
progress="0.0" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="65.0" fitWidth="223.0" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="16.0" 
pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@EX-Logo.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="38.0" layoutY="137.0" text="Modelo Etiqueta:" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="cbEtiquetas" layoutX="120.0" layoutY="133.0" prefHeight="22.0" 
prefWidth="146.0" promptText="Selecione um modelo" />
      <Pane layoutX="734.0" layoutY="133.0" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="133.0" 
style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-background-color: silver;">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="13.0" layoutY="4.0" text="Configurações: F12" 
textFill="#e80c0c">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="11.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o código do seu FXML com defeito?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo.Eu colo ele  aqui, mas nao aparece. Ele aponta erro nesta linha `<TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />` dizendo que esta constante nao esta definida pra minha tableview. Nao sei se ja estava assim quando funcionava

Comment: Resolvi criando outro arquivo com outro nome, colando o código da janela bugada. Não sei pq bugou  e eu havia deletado o arquivo e criado um novo com o mesmo nome, copiado o mesmo código do arquivo bugado e nao funcionou.

Comment: Tem que usar o { } para colar código, principalmente se for XML

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode acontecer por conta do erro no seu FXML ou por um bug na janela. Para resolver a primeira situação basta retirar a o código abaixo (Aqui mesmo com o erro abriu normalmente, talvez por conta do cache).

```
<columnResizePolicy>
    <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
</columnResizePolicy>
```

O erro que apresenta é que essa constante não está definida pro TableView, mas parece que o aparecimento dele está relacionado com um [bug no netbeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=256522). Todavia, existe a segunda situação que é relatada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780618/can-not-open-fxml-after-a-while) (créditos ao autor), ela apresenta o seguinte *workaround*:

> Windows XP/7

- Abra o gerenciador de tarefas (Ctrl + Alt + Del)
- Vá para a aba "Aplicativos"
- Clique com o botão direito no SceneBuilder (seuArquivo.fxml)
- Selecione 'Maximizar'

> Windows 8+

- Abra o gerenciador de tarefas (Ctrl + Alt + Del)
- Vá para a aba "Processos"
- Clique no menu dropdown do JavaFX Scene Builder x.x.exe
- Encontre o arquivo FXML file that is not opening
- Botão direito > Maximizar

**Bônus:**

Pelo que entendi desse erro você está tentando bloquear a ação padrão de redimensionar o tamanho das colunas no TableView. A má notícia não há uma forma fácil de fazer isso, por que essa função está bugada. Segue como se faz isso em JavaFX sem FXML:

```
// Coluna 1 com 25% do tamanho total e assim por diante
coluna1.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableview.widthProperty().multiply(0.25));
coluna2.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableview.widthProperty().multiply(0.05));
coluna3.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableview.widthProperty().multiply(0.45));
coluna4.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableview.widthProperty().multiply(0.15));
```

Basicamente você associa o tamanho total do TableView ao tamanho das colunas, dada uma porcentagem, isso faz com que a setinha não redimensione a coluna. Você teria que adaptar para usar em FXML ([tente isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293438/how-to-give-tablecolumns-a-relative-width-in-fxml)).

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema hoje e acredito que seja algum problema no cache mesmo.
Eu troquei o nome do FXML e consegui abrir o arquivo no Scene Builder, depois voltei com o nome original do arquivo e abriu normalmente.